# why python pandas not able to generate xlsx file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to achieve below tasks:

**traverse_dir() function**

```
- read a root directory, and get the names of the sub directories.
- read the sub directories and see if 'installed-files.json' file is present.
- if the 'installed-files.json' file is present in all the directories, then open them and create a excel file out of the JSON file those are present in all the sub directories.
```

**filter_apk() function**

```
- read the excel file generated in the first function and create another excel file that will store only file names ending with '.apk'.
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
def traverse_dir(rootDir, file_name):
    dir_names = []
    for names in os.listdir(rootDir):
        entry_path = os.path.join(names)
        if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
            dir_names.append(entry_path)
            for i in dir_names:
                if file_name in i:
                    with open(file_name) as jf:
                        data = json.load(jf)
                        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                        new_df = df[df.columns.difference(['SHA256'])]
                        new_df.to_excel('abc.xlsx')

def filter_apk():
    traverse_dir(rootDir, file_name)
    old_xl = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx')
    a = old_xl[old_xl["Name"].str.contains("\.apk")]
    a.to_excel('zybg.xlsx')

rootDir = '<root path where sub folders resides>'
file_name = 'installed-files.json'
filter_apk()
```

Note:

- I have tested the code separately on single folder, and its working like charm. I am only facing issues when I am trying to work with multiple directories.
- In fact, in the 1st function `traverse_dir()`, I am able to list the sub directories.

I am getting below errors while executing the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Jenkins.py", line 36, in <module>
    filter_apk()
  File "Jenkins.py", line 30, in filter_apk
    old_xl = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx')

    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc.xlsx'
```

Why the file is not getting generated? Any suggestions?

**modified code**

```
def traverse_dir(rootDir, file_name):
    dir_names = []
    for names in os.listdir(rootDir):
        entry_path = os.path.join(rootDir, names)
        if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
            dir_names.append(entry_path)
            for fil_name in dir_names:
                file_path = os.path.join(entry_path, fil_name, file_name)
                print(file_path)
                if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    with open(file_path) as jf:
                        data = json.load(jf)
                        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
                        new_df = df[df.columns.difference(['SHA256'])]
                        new_df1 = df1[df.columns.difference(['SHA256'])]
                        with pd.ExcelWriter('abc.xlsx') as writer:
                            new_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='BRA', index=False)
                            new_df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CNA', index=False)
                else:
                    raise FileNotFoundError

rootDir = <path to subdirs
file_name = 'installed-files.json'
traverse_dir(rootDir, file_name)
```

Comment: The error is about reading, not 'generating the file'. The error says that the file does not exist in the folder it's trying to read from, does it?.

Comment: exactly, since the file is not getting generated, so its not being read and hence the error

Comment: Your code never calls that function, so of course it's never generated!

Comment: that function is being called inside the 2nd function.

Comment: It can't be calling it.  Debug it and you'll see.

Comment: As I said, its working for single jSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `if file_name in i:` is always false, hence no xlsx file created.
You may need to make some changes to test for the file existence, for example:

```
import os
def traverse_dir(rootDir, file_name):
    dir_names = []
    for names in os.listdir(rootDir):
        entry_path = os.path.join(names)
        if os.path.isdir(entry_path):
            dir_names.append(entry_path)
            for i in dir_names:
                file_path=os.path.join(rootDir,i,file_name)
                if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    with open(file_path) as jf:
                        data = json.load(jf)
                        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                        new_df = df[df.columns.difference(['SHA256'])]
                        new_df.to_excel('abc.xlsx')

def filter_apk():
    traverse_dir(rootDir, file_name)
    old_xl = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx')
    a = old_xl[old_xl["Name"].str.contains("\.apk")]
    a.to_excel('zybg.xlsx')

rootDir = '<root path where sub folders resides>'
file_name = 'installed-files.json'
filter_apk()
```

Comment: as per your suggestion, I have modified the program and have accommodated the changes, and since I have files in different directories. So I have made additional changes as well. I have updated the main post with the modified program. This time I only called the 1st function. There were no errors, but "abc.xlsx" still didn't get generated. Had the path be wrong, then I could have seen any error. But nothing.

Comment: but if abc.xlsx is not generated then old_xl = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx') should produce an error

Comment: please notice that you are creating abc.xlsx in the directory you are running the script, is this what you need? maybe you want to write and read abc.xlsx using full path

Comment: as said, right now I am only testing the 1st function. If that works, then I will go to the 2nd function. So, I am only calling the function "traverse_dir()"

Comment: try to add print(os.getcwd()) just before new_df.to_excel , this should tell you where the file is being created. If you don't get anything printed then is because if os.path.isfile(file_path) is false, in which case try a print(file_path) before the "if"

Comment: what you say is correct. But this is crazy, as I could see the JSON file inside the sub directories. This means, the program is not able to read the subdirectories.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. I have added the modified code in the main post. But now only issue is happening is that , my program is going inside 'if' and 'else' both condition. i.e, while the program is able to locate the JSON file & create xlsx file. But it also throwing exception "filenotfound". plz check if you could.

Comment: that is because the error is being raised every time the file is not found in any directory. You may need to raise the error only if the file is not found after traversing all the directories. There are many ways to deal with that, if you need help with it, please raise a separate question otherwise this one will get too confusing for someone searching to solve a similar issue, thanks